# React app is catching errors that doesnot matter usually

Tags: reactjs

I am working on MUI template and when I make changes i have seen it is showing errors that usually does not matter. e.g if I import a component in a file but i decide not to use it , react will show me error saying something like this

```
Line 12:3:  'Story' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
```

in one of my file I decided not to use this (story) component and react showed me this error. its annoying when u have a lot of changes to make and you keep getting these kinda errors. how can I get rid of these kind of errors permanently

Comment: This is an eslint warning. Either remove the unused vars or disable the eslint rule so it won't warn about `no-unused-vars`

Answer (score 1):

First solution is to remove any unused imports, and declarations of variables/methods/components.

The second solution is to paste this link above your line

`//eslint-disable-next-line`

Comment: what i wanted to ask, is there any particular file i can remove from my template so i dont see these errors anywhere in my react app.

Comment: No. The simple solution is removing any unused code